# Access CheckBoxList.DataValueField value through jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, checkboxlist

In a `CheckBoxList`, how can I get the checkbox `value` that is set using `checkboxlist.DataValueField`?

In C# the value is accessible if I call the `checkboxItem.value` but in HTML the value renders as `value="on"`.

EDIT: If this is not possible, is there an attribute I can add via a data source or to each `ListItem` individually that is accessible through HTML? Such as the `input` attribute `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DataValueField** is binding of column from checkbox datasource to checkbox value. Values in HTML are from datasource column with name from **DataValueField** and this field is not visible in HTML. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111634/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050703-1.aspx) should explain it further.

EDIT:

You can add attribute to ListItem. You didnt provide any example of what You have now, but You can define checkboxlist:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

add listitem with attribute in code behind:

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("text_value", "value_value", true);
li.Attributes.Add("id", "id_value");

CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(li);
```

This will result in generated markup like this:

```
<span id="id_value">
    <input id="MainContent_CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" 
        name="ctl00$MainContent$CheckBoxList1$0" value="value_value">
    <label for="MainContent_CheckBoxList1_0">text_value</label>
</span>
```

So You can use span id to access Your input field from jQuery:

```
jQuery('#id_value input').val()
```

You may also be interested in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125132807/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091405-1.aspx) article.

Comment: Same if I set the value on each `ListItem` instead of using `DataValueField`?